# RecyclerView,CardView, DrawerActivity, Adapter Путаница в голове.Как по нажатию в навбаре открывать фрагмент который в свою очередь отображает список?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

```
public class territoryFragment extends Fragment {

    public RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewTerr;
    private static final String ARG_COLUMN_COUNT = "column-count";
    private int mColumnCount = 1;
    private OnListFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


    public territoryFragment() {
    }

    public static territoryFragment newInstance(int columnCount) {
        territoryFragment fragment = new territoryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT, columnCount);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mColumnCount = getArguments().getInt(ARG_COLUMN_COUNT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_territory_list, container, false);
        String[] terrNames = new String[];
        recyclerViewTerr = (RecyclerView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.territory_view);
        recyclerViewTerr.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return view;

        // Set the adapter
        if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
            if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
            } else {
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
            }
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerAdapter(String));
        }
        return view;
    }
    public class TerrHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView mtextView;
        public TerrHolder (View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            mtextView = (TextView) itemView;
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }
    public interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {

        void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyItem item);
    }
}
```

**Отдельный Класс Адаптера**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends 


RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
     public String[] recycler;

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private CardView cardView;
        public ViewHolder (CardView v) {

            super(v);
            cardView = v;
        }
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(String[]recycler){

        this.recycler = recycler;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType){
        CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.oblast_card,parent,false);
        return  new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position){
        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
        //добавить ресурсы фото
        //ImageView imageView = (ImageView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.)
       // Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(image[position]);
        //посмотреть в книге!
        TextView textView =(TextView)cardView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        textView.setText(recycler[position]);

    }   

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Thing;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Fragment fpoisk;
    Fragment fterritory;

    Fragment fsovety;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        fpoisk = new Fragment();
        fterritory = new Fragment();
        fsovety = new Fragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.soveti) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PoleznieSovetiActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.nav_territory) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.content_main, fterritory);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_sovety) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.content_main, fsovety);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_poisk) {
             ftrans.replace(R.id.content_main,fpoisk);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }
        ftrans.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя fTerritory не является твоим `territoryFragment`, он является просто `Fragment`'ом. Поменяй тип для `fTerritory` и инициализируй его методом `territoryFragment.newInstance(int)`